# Could not listen on port 1527 on host localhost

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new with Neatbenas. When I create java db, and try to connect with it, the output display error message

> Could not listen on port 1527 on host localhost: 
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed).

Could anyone tell me how to solve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: there is already a connection to this port. try changing port.

Comment: If you don't want to change port, you need to find out what's already running there. Most likely, it's a previous instance of your app, still running. Find it and close it.

Comment: google search  as `netbeans port 1527` shows some promising results. try them.

Answer (score 0):

To find the process that keeps the busy port, try the following command:

> netstat -ano | find "1527"

This will show a line with the port and the identifier of the process. e.g.:

> TCP    127.0.0.1:1527         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

2268 Once you have the process ID (e.g. 2268), run the following
command for release the port (this will kill the process):

taskkill /F /PID 2268

Here it is the Linux solution:

> lsof -Pnl +M -i6 | grep 1527

Produces:

> java    31139     1001   32u  IPv6 114916062      0t0  TCP
>   127.0.0.1:1527 (LISTEN)

Killed with:

> kill -9 31139

Comment: This is a Windows-specific solution. Is the OP using Windows?

Comment: That's what I thought...this solution is OS specific.

Comment: somehow this does not show anything on my Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

If you know what port the process is running you can type: lsof -i:.

For instance, lsof -i:8080, to list the process (pid) running on port 8080.

Then kill the process with kill

In windows

netstat -ano
will list all the protocols, ports and processes listening . Use

taskkill -pid "proces to kill" /f
to kill the process listening to the port. e.g

taskkill -pid 431 /f